Seek the maximum of $|z_1^3 + z_2^3 + z_3^3 + z_4^3 + z_5^3|$ subject to complex numbers $|z_i|\le 1, \forall i$ and $\sum z_i = 0$

Let $z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4, z_5 \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|z_i| \le 1, \forall i$ and $z_1 + z_2 + z_3 + z_4 + z_5 = 0$. Find the maximum of $|z_1^3 + z_2^3 + z_3^3 + z_4^3 + z_5^3|$.

This is the case $n = 5$ of the question.
I post this separately which focuses more on the case $n = 5$.
In the comment there, @Martin R pointed out for $n=5$, $f(1, a, a, \bar{a}, \bar{a}) = \frac{15}{4}$
with $a = -\frac14 + \mathrm{i} \frac{\sqrt{15}}{4}$ looks like the maximum by numerical simulation. I believe this is helpful. We see that at maximum, it holds that $|z_i|=1, \forall i$.
In contrast, for $n=4$, at maximum, exactly one of $|z_i|, i=1, 2, 3, 4$ is (strictly) less than $1$. The strategy in proving the case $n=4$ is to prove that at most one of $|z_i|, i=1, 2, 3, 4$ is (strictly) less than $1$. The proof of $n=4$ can be found in the question and also here.
Some thoughts.

Way 1: WLOG, we may assume that $z_5 = 1$. Then $z_4 = -1 - z_1 - z_2 - z_3$. We have
$$f = |z_1^3 + z_2^3 + z_3^3 + (1 + z_1 + z_2 + z_3)^3 + 1|.$$
The constraints are $|z_1| \le 1, |z_2| \le 1, |z_3|\le 1$ and $|1 + z_1 + z_2 + z_3| \le 1$.

Way 2: Note that the expressions do not change if we replace $(z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4, z_5)$ with $(\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}z_1, \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}z_2, \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}z_3, \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}z_4, \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}z_5)$
for any $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$.
WLOG, assume that
$z_1^3 + z_2^3 + z_3^3 + z_4^3 + z_5^3$
is real. Let $z_i = a_i + \mathrm{i}b_i, i = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$. We have
$$z_1^3 + z_2^3 + z_3^3 + z_4^3 + z_5^3 = \sum_{i=1}^5 (a_i^3 - 3a_ib_i^2) + \mathrm{i}\cdot \sum_{i=1}^5 (3a_i^2b_i - b_i^3) \in \mathbb{R}.$$
The problem becomes:
Let $a_i, b_i, i= 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ be reals such that
$a_i^2 + b_i^2 \le 1, \forall i$,
and $\sum_{i=1}^5 (3a_i^2b_i - b_i^3) = 0$, and $\sum_{i=1}^5 a_i = \sum_{i=1}^5 b_i = 0$. Find the maximum of
$\sum_{i=1}^5 (a_i^3 - 3a_ib_i^2)$.


